# how to push a new item into a deeply nested Record in immutableJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, immutable.js

I'm trying to push a new item into a deeply nested immutable record.

```
  const i = Immutable.Record({
    nested: new (Immutable.Record({
      someKey: [{id:1,name:'adam'}, {id:2,name:'steve'}],
    })),
  });
  const myMap = new i;
  const myNewMap = myMap.updateIn(['nested', 'someKey'], (fav)=>    fav.push({id:3,name:'dan'}));

  console.log(myNewMap.toJS());
```

what I expect is to update the nested list with the new value, but the actual output is

```
  [object Object] {
  nested: [object Object] {
    someKey: 3
    }
  }
```

so Im doing something wrong, so how would I go about updating the record with the new value ?

here is the jsbin for the example
http://jsbin.com/nipolimuyu/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `return` statement in a function you pass to `updateIn` (note that Array.push does NOT return a resulting array!). It should be:

```
const myNewMap = myMap.updateIn(
  ['nested', 'someKey'], 
  (fav) => {
    fav.push({id:3,name:'dan'})
    return fav
  })
```

Comment: Perfect :) If it works for you, could you please accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this code is quite right... it should be... const myNewMap = myMap.updateIn(
  ['nested', 'someKey'], 
  (fav) => {
    return fav.push({id:3,name:'dan'});
  })

Comment: That's basically the same as the non-functioning code that was put to the question (the syntax is different, but the meaning is the same). Note that we're dealing with standard i.e. mutable Array here.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful here.

Your initial obj should all be an immutableJS obj. You can use fromJS().

In your example, you need to add your array as an ImmutableJS list

```
const i = Immutable.Record({
    nested: new (Immutable.Record({
    someKey: new Immutable.List([{id:1,name:'adam'}, {id:2,name:'steve'}]),
  })),
});
// The bad way, add a normal JS array to an immutableJS Record/map
const i = Immutable.Record({
    nested: new (Immutable.Record({
    someKey: [{id:1,name:'adam'}, {id:2,name:'steve'}],
  })),
});
```

So at the end you just need to do like you wanted

```
const myNewMap = myMap.updateIn(['nested', 'someKey'], fav => fav.push({id:3,name:'dan'}));
```

So now you can use the immutableJS push() function that return a new immutableJS object.